# Char array, why must I "dereference" a string of a single character to assign it

Tags: c, string, char

```
int main() {
    char test[15] = "Hallo World";
    test[1] = *"e";
}
```

To change the 2nd letter to `e`, I have to deference the string `"e"`. I couldn't find any information about why this is so. If I don't dereference the string `"e"`, test ends up becoming `"H$llo World"`. Could someone enlighten me?

Comment: Because `test[1]` is a `char` and `"e"` is a `char*`.

Comment: (You obviously haven't yet figured out pointers and strings in C.)

Comment: Get a better compiler (or learn how to use yours properly) to make it show warnings and diagnostics; you should be able to figure this out just from the machine-generated messages. (I.e. no need to invoke human attention for a problem that a machine could solve better.)

Comment: The `$` you get is the value of the lowest 8 bits of the full address of the constant string. (And you can't *rely* on it being this same value, for every program, compiler, and/or computer. Better not use it at all.)

Answer (score 1):

A character literal in C is spelled with apostrophes:

```
test[1] = 'e';
```

Of course you could go through any number of obfuscating, complex expressions that produce a character value, but this is the most direct and deliberate way to achieve the intended behaviour.

Comment: Oh wow. That definitely was distinguished in class. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this code snippet

```
int main() {
    char test[15] = "Hallo World";
    test[1] = *"e";
}
```

`"e"` is a string literal that has type `char[2]` that is it ia an array that contains two characters `'e'` and the terminating zero `'\0'`

Instead of the string literal you could use character literal `'e'`. In this case you could write

```
    test[1] = 'e';
```

As for the string literal then expression `*"e"` is equivalent to `"e"[0]` that is it returns the first character of the array that corresponds to the string literal.

Take into account that sometimes there are used manifest constants for some string literals in C. For example

```
#define YES_NO "y/n"
```

In this case there is nothing strange if you will meet code

```
if ( c == *YES_NO ) { /* some stuff */ }
```

or
    if ( c == YES_NO[0] ) { /* some stuff */ }